# Can unobtrusive Javascript event be used in document head?

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events, unobtrusive-javascript

There are a few examples on unobtrusive events for pure JS. Most of questions in this subjects  are practically answered with jQuery solutions. I wonder how this simple example works. As I tested, this function inside the document head perfectly works for click on the entire document

```
document.onclick=function(){alert("OK");}
```

but this does NOT work for click on `<div id="test">CLICK</div>`

```
document.getElementById("test").onclick=function(){alert("OK");}
```

How to capture click on an element for unobtrusive JS function?

**UPDATED QUESTION:** Following the answer by [ascii-lime](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772035/ascii-lime), how unobtruive Javascript events can be place in the document 'head`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/tSvAE/).

Make sure your script is running after your `<div>` exists, either by putting your script after the `<div>`, or by running it in a `window.onload` event handler.

Alternatively you can attach the `onclick` to the document (since the document definitely exists before your script runs) and then detect which element was clicked [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/S6eqG/):

```
document.onclick = function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    if(e.target.id == 'test')
        alert('OK');
}
```

Comment: Your answer is perfect and clearified the vague issue, but I updated the question, as this should be the question of some other people too.

Comment: Crystal clear! and I can claim there is no such clear explanation over the internet, as I searched a lot. I believe this will help others people searching for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code in JSFiddle.net and it seems to be running.

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/kNFrz/

I have tested using Chrome 19.0 and IE 9.0